# How to define a New SailJS Session Store

Tags: node.js, session, sails.js

Can anyone provide me reference or sample code on how to define a Custom Sessions Store in SailsJS. Currently, only MongoDB and Redis are provided, but I would like to use Disk as a Session Adapter on development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/session-file-store

Here is what needs to be done in config/session.js

adapter: 'session-file-store'

Other configuration options as required